# Callback and code factoring

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I was programming one controller which most of its methods call at the end `respond_with` method. So an idea comes to my mind "*Can I use a callback to don't have to repeat that line more than once?*"

Maybe it's some extreme and it's worthless but I need to know that. So I tested it but it don't work as expected and I really want to understand it. Whats the difference between both approaches?

**Approach 1**

```
def new
  @user = User.new
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

**Approach 2**

```
after_action :respond_with_call, only: [:new]  

def new
  @user = User.new
end

def respond_with_call
  respond_with(@user)
end
```

Comment: You say that it doesn't work.  Is you ***core*** question "How do I make it work"?

Comment: Well, if you know other approach similar to the second, let me know ^^

Comment: You could write a rack app that looked for certain situations, like a route, and then re-wrote the response with other data.  That data could be `@user` marshalled into a header value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`respond_with` does not work in and `after_action`, since the response has already been sent to the client.

Very similar [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6118639/rails-respond-with-how-does-it-work)